# Populate a List and a subList via a class

Tags: c#, list, class

I'm sorry I don't know how to properly formulate the question because I'm already confused myself.

Anyhow, I have 3 classes.

1. ProductPageModel.
2. ProductName
3. SubProduct.

I'm trying to populate a list with a 'Sublist' (?). For example. There can be  "*Helmet*", and Product "*Helmet*" can have a SubProducts "*Red Helmet*", "*Gren Helmet*".

Now, I'm trying to connect all the lists and such in my ProductPageModel. My code is as follows:

**ProductPageModel**

```
 public class ProductPageModel
    {
        public List<ProductName> productNames { get; set; }
        public ProductPageModel()
        {
            productNames = new List<ProductName>();
        }
        internal void AddFel(string product, string subCategory)
        {
            if (productNames.Any(containsName => product == containsName.Productname))
            {
            }
            else
            {
                productNames.Add(new ProductName { Productname = product });
            }
        }
        public List<ProductName> ProductNames
        {
            get => productNames;
            set => productNames = value;
        }

    }
```

**ProductName**

```
 public class ProductName
    {
        public string Productname { get; set; }

        public ProductName()
        {
            subProducts = new List<SubProduct>();
        }

        public List<SubProduct> subProducts;

        public List<SubProduct> SubProducts
        {
            get => subProducts;
            set => subProducts = value;
        }

    }
```

**SubProduct**

```
public class SubProduct
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I can populate and show the info in my "productNames" list, but I can't seem to populate my subProducts list.
How do I do that?

Comment: Um, you have a serious naming issue. `ProductName` should probably be `Product` and both `ProductsNamesInClassProductName` and `NameInSubProduct` should just be `Name` (or if you want to be more explicit, then `ProductName` and `SubProductName` respectively). If I misunderstood what those classes represent, please let me know (it might be better to [edit] the question and clarify).

Comment: Something like `productNames[i].SubProducts.Add(new SubProduct())`

Comment: While adding  ---> `productNames.Add(new ProductName { ProductsNamesInClassProductName = product , SubProducts = new List<SubProduct>() { new SubProduct() {NameInSubProduct  = subCategory}} })`

Comment: Please don't edit the question to provide a solution or "thank you" comments. If you've figured out the solution to your problem and want to provide an answer, you may do so by clicking the "Answer Your Question" button below. I've removed the "answered" section from your question but you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67773260/2).

Comment: On another note, I see you've made some improvements to the names but you left out the name of the `ProductName` class. If that class represents a product, then you should name it `Product`. Then, you could its property either `Name` or `ProductName`. Try to stick to the naming/capitalization convention as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) and [here](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md). Good luck :)